# How to filter items by property of an object inside an object array in OpenSearch.Client

Tags: c#, .net, opensearch

This is my object

```
public class Shoe
{
    public List<ShoeSize> ShoeSizes { get; set; }
}

public class ShoeSize
{
    public string SizeName { get; set; }
}
```

How do I use OpenSearch.Client for .NET to retrieve all shoes that contain ShoeSize with SizeName "XL" ?

I couldn't find any method that even suggests the functionality I'm looking for.

So this is where I'm at currently.

```
var index = "shoes";
return new SearchDescriptor<Shoe>()
    .Index(index)
    .Query(x => x
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(
                m => m.Term(t=> t.Field(a => a.ShoeSizes)))));
```

Thank you